# GroupBy with IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a database with 3 Columns (Energy, Power, TIme(it contains and integer with the timestamp).

I already exerted 200 rows of this database in an IQueryable called "todayPower". Now i want to group these lines to Minutes, with the following code. I get the error

[image]

Code here:

```
 var todayPower = _context.Mains.Where(x => x.Time >= beginning
                                         && x.Time <= end);
var groupedPower = todayPower.GroupBy(Items => Items.Time.Minutes);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Time has the type int

Comment: Why do you need grouping?  Some aggregates?

Comment: the timestamps are in interval of 20s i want them to group them in 15min intervalls

Comment: Do you have ValueConverter on this column?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: C# is a language of types - show the types for your objects (i.e. class definitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it changing to a list:

```
 var todayPower = _context.Mains.Where(x => x.Time >= beginning
                                     && x.Time <= end).ToList();
 var groupedPower = todayPower.GroupBy(Items => Items.Time.Minutes);
```

I was getting the error: client side GroupBy not supported, so I fixed it like that

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Hm, I don't understand what type Time is. You said int, but it has a Minutes property and it can't be DateTime which has Minute property

Comment: I fixed it by changing the type from int to Date Time in my Db, thanks